# Ruby on rails. Mailboxer, move multiple conversations to trash. Undefined method for #<Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, mailboxer, recycle-bin

I am struggling with sending multiple items to the trash folder using checkboxes. I get an

```
undefined method `move_to_trash' for #<Array:0x007...etc...
```

`move_to_trash` works fine on single conversations.

I have a checkbox next to each conversation rendered by a partial, and a button to delete all checked conversations.

Anyway, my conversations controller:

```
def trash_multiple
    @convo = mailbox.conversations.find(params[:trash_id])
    @convo.move_to_trash(current_user)
    redirect_to mailbox_inbox_path
  end
```

The checkbox which is in a partial, placed next to each conversation:

```
<%= check_box_tag "trash_id[]", conversation.id %>
```

The id's are correct.

The form:

```
<div class="message-cont">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <%= form_tag trash_multiple_conversations_path, method: :post do %>
    <%= submit_tag "Trash selected" %>
      <div class="panel-body">
         <% if is_conversation %>
            <%= render 'conversations/form' %>
        <% else %>
        <div class="msg-cnter">
        <%= render partial: 'conversations/conversation', collection: messages %>
        </div>
        <% end %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my routes:

```
resources :conversations do
    member do
      post :reply
      post :trash
      post :untrash
    end
    collection do
      get :trashbin
      post :empty_trash
      post :trash_multiple
    end
  end
```

Any hints on getting this to work for an array would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

SOLUTION:

changing controller to:

```
def trash_multiple
    params[:trash_id].each do |element|
    @convo = mailbox.conversations.find(element)
    @convo.move_to_trash(current_user)
    end
    redirect_to mailbox_inbox_path
  end
```

as stated by @wpp has fixed this.

Comment: What do your params look like?

Comment: "trash_id"=>["147", "139"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> move_to_trash works fine on single conversations.

My guess is that you want to invoke the `move_to_trash` method on each element of the array:

```
array.each do |element|
  element.move_to_trash
end
```

or shorter:

```
array.map(&:move_to_trash)
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I wanted. def trash_multiple
    params[:trash_id].each do |element|
    @convo = mailbox.conversations.find(element)
    @convo.move_to_trash(current_user)
    end
    redirect_to mailbox_inbox_path
  end has fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 @convo.each {|c| c.move_to_trash(current_user) }
```